# How does mpdf prevent line break on td

Tags: php, mpdf

How does mpdf prevent newlines on td, I want the text to exceed the td width and the automatic characters are replaced with '...'
eg:
[before png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5juZ4.png)

I try to calculate the width occupied by each character, and use '...' to splicing the excess part, but it still can't meet the requirements, and some characters still read line break
[after png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qQ9zb.png)

php code

```php
$config = [
    'mode' => 'utf-8',
    'margin_top' => 13,
    'margin_left' => 10,
    'margin_right' => 10,
    'format' => 'A4',
    'dpi' => 300,
];
$mpdf = new Mpdf($config);
$mpdf->autoScriptToLang = true;
$mpdf->autoLangToFont = true;
$html = file_get_contents('./test.html');
$mpdf->SetFont('sun-exta', null, 8.16);
$subStr2 = function (string $s) use ($mpdf) {
    $totalWidth = 167.11608661417;
    $w = 0;
    $dotWidth = 3 * $mpdf->GetCharWidthNonCore('.', false) * Mpdf::SCALE;
    $w += $dotWidth;
    for ($i = 0, $clen = mb_strlen($s); $i < $clen; $i ++) {
        $c = mb_substr($s, $i, 1, 'UTF-8');

        $cw = ($mpdf->GetCharWidthNonCore($c, false) * Mpdf::SCALE);
        $w += $cw;
        if ($w > $totalWidth) {
      
            return mb_substr($s, 0, $i, 'UTF-8') . '...';
        }
    }
    return $s;
};
$pros =  [
    [1,"算法算法算法算法算法", "型号", "个", "10", "11.00", "111.00", "-"],
    [2,"翻法春天带着一阵春雨悄悄得走来了春雨淅淅沥沥地下", "型号", "个", "10", "11.00", "111.00", "-"],
    [3,"vasadHs算asdasHhsdf算法算OEHKSHs法算法算法", "型号", "个", "10", "11.00", "111.00", "-"],
    [4,"shdf eritue kl翻 (-)sdhfeyytk s kdhfshfk word word word word word word word", "型号", "个", "10", "11.00", "111.00", "-"],
];

foreach ($pros as $item) {
    $table .= '<tr>'
        . '<td style="width: 132px;">' . $item[0] . '</td>'
        . '<td style="width: 715px;">' .  $subStr2($item[1]) . '</td>'
        . '<td style="width: 269px;">' . $item[2] . '</td>'
        . '<td style="width: 194px;">' . $item[3] . '</td>'
        . '<td style="width: 194px;">' . $item[4] . '</td>'
        . '<td style="width: 213px;">' . $item[5] . '</td>'
        . '<td style="width: 286px;">' . $item[6] . '</td>'
        . '<td style="width: 245px;">' . $item[7] . '</td></tr>';
}
$mpdf->writeHtml(str_replace('{{Tdata}}', $table, $html));
$mpdf->Output( './test.pdf', Destination::FILE);
```

test.html

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
  <style>
    .table {
      margin: 30px 0;
      width: 100%;
      border-right:4px solid #000;
      border-bottom:4px solid #000;
      border-collapse: collapse;
      hyphens: none;
    }
    .table td, .table th {
      hyphens: none;
      text-align: center;
      border-left:4px solid #000;
      border-top:4px solid #000;
      empty-cells:show;
    }
    .table th{
      height: 68px;
    }
    .table td {
      height: 110px;
      font-size: 34px;
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
<table class="table">
  <thead>
  <tr>
    <th style="width: 132px;">num</th>
    <th>product name</th>
    <th style="width: 269px;">unit</th>
    <th style="width: 194px;">type1</th>
    <th style="width: 194px;">type</th>
    <th style="width: 213px;">number</th>
    <th style="width: 286px;">price</th>
    <th style="width: 245px;">remark</th>
  </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
  {{Tdata}}
  </tbody>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

output file test.pdf[test.pdf](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ngmJh.png)

Comment: Can you please include the code which isn't working.

Comment: @NigelRen I updated the code inside the question